# Add List to ListBuffer with foreach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I'm using Mahout FPGrowth Algorithm, but stuck with the preprocessing of the data.

The input of the FPGrowth algorithm is:
          val data: List[JPair[JList[String], JLong]]

In the early stage of my work i tested it with hardcoded input data.

```
val data: List[JPair[JList[String], JLong]] = List(
  new JPair(List("bread", "beer", "fries", "butter"), 1L),
  new JPair(List("milk", "bread"), 1L),
  new JPair(List("butter", "beer", "fries"), 1L),
  new JPair(List("bread", "beer"), 1L),
  new JPair(List("milk", "butter", "bread", "beer"), 1L)
)
```

that worked. but i want to fill the List automatically. I read that in scala this is possible with ListBuffers. I tried to fill the ListBuffer in a foreach step. but that does not work.

```
parsedData.foreach( p =>  ListBuf += new JPair(p.str, 1L) )
val ItemSet = ListBuf.toList
```

at the end of the app the list (ItemSet) is still empty.

has anybody an idea??

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing the code that initializes `ListBuf` it's somehow difficult to tell, but let me suggest you a nicer approach which doesn't involve mutable collections.

You want to produce a new collection by applying a transformation to each element of `parsedData`, and that's exactly what `map` does. Here's an example

```
val data = parsedData.map(new JPair(JString(_.str), JLong(1L)))
```

I explicitly used `JString` and `JLong` constructors so that you don't have to annotate the type.

Comment: Hey Gabriele, thanks for your reply. The initialization of the ListBuffer is var ListBuf = ListBuffer[JPair[JList[String], JLong]](). It works if I add an element to ListBuf with ListBuf += new JPair(List("test", "test2"), 1L). Your suggestion with a map I tried in a similar way, but gives the folowing errors: - object java.lang.Long is not a value
 - missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => 
  x$2.str)

Comment: Edit: if a use var data:List[JPair[JList[String], JLong]] = parsedData.map(c => new JPair(c.str, 1L)) i get: - type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.mahout.common.Pair[List[String],scala.Long]] 
  required: List[org.apache.mahout.common.Pair[java.util.List[String],java.lang.Long]]
 - type mismatch; found : Array[org.apache.mahout.common.Pair[scala.collection.immutable.List[String],scala.Long]] 
  required: scala.collection.immutable.List[org.apache.mahout.common.Pair[java.util.List[String],java.lang.Long]]